# Remote Postgres to Postgres data

Tags: python, postgresql, remote-access

I am working on a project now where I need to load daily data from one psql database into another one (both databases are on separate remote machines).
The Postgres version I'm using is 9.5, and due to our infrastructure, I am currently doing this using python scripts, which works fine for now, although I was wondering:

Is it possible to do this using psql commands that I can easily schedule? or is python a flexible enough appproach for future developments?

EDIT:

The main database contains a backend connected directly to a website and the other contains an analytics system which basically only needs to read the main db's data and store future transformations of it.
The latency is not very important, what is important is the reliability and simplicity.

Comment: What is the status of the second postgres box? Is it a backup? Do you do other writes or modifications of the data on that box? What sort of latency is acceptable for data lag between the two boxes?

Comment: Added an edit to tge question

Comment: Have you considered setting up a read slave? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION

Comment: Makes sense, but I would prefer an approach with no redundant data sources since both databases will be considered to be for production.

Comment: I mean you could set up your analytics database as a read slave. When I've done this in the past for nightly backups, I'll just reenable read replication at some point (say 2 AM Pacific) and once the read slave has caught up, I will disable read replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you can use psql and an ssh connection if you want.

this approach (or using pg_dump) can be useful as way to reduce the effexcts of latency.

however note that the SQL `insert`...`values` command can insert several rows in a single command.  When I use python scripts to migrate data I build insert commands that insert up-to 1000 rows, thus reducing latency by a factor of 1000,

Another approach worth considering is [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/dblink.html) which allows postgres to query a remote postgres directly, so you could do a select from the remote database and insert the result into a local table.

[Postgres-FDW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/postgres-fdw.html) may be worth a look too.